# Visual Studio Build fails with "object not declared" on substring of keyword

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild

This is pretty weird - I am getting "object not declared" on variables that are a substring  of a piece of code. I have pasted an example below.

[image: error image snippet]
<sub>(source: [metroplexconsulting.com](http://metroplexconsulting.com/Images/Capture.png))</sub>

In the error line above the 'les' from Handles is being taken as an object name. (!?!)

It felt like maybe the cache was corrupt, but I have run Clean, and gone in and deleted all output files and folders and the problem persists. I had just moved this web site and renamed it, so maybe that is a clue. But I don't see any residuals in the files of that move.

Thanks for any assistance!

EDIT: As you will see in the comments below this seems to be tied to mixing old style web pages with new ones. I was updating an existing site. I do not know if it is related to VB specifically. But I can now create the compiler error at will by adding a new asp.net page to an older site (that has had its .Net target set to v4.5). Workaround is to copy an existing page and modify it and keep autowireup turned off, etc.

Comment: Check the code before the Page_Load method. I suppose that something is not quite right there.

Comment: I had commented out a section and I erased those comments. There is also a reference to an object that the code uses. After making changes, the compiler now takes a different substring of a different line and give me the same error on that line. One of the errors is:

Dim MachNum As String = Request.QueryString("MachNum")

'QuerySt' is not a member of 'System.Web.HttpRequest'.

Comment: ok, have uninstalled resharper and am running only one instance of VS and I got a "Visual Studio has stopped working". Ugh - maybe time to uninstall and re-install VS.

Comment: I moved the project to a different machine and backed it up one check-in, and everything came up fine. I then added a new page and made a few edits and wham! It came back! So I then knew that I didn't have a corrupted VS install. I discovered that VS doesn't like to add new asp.net 3.5 pages to an older set of pages (at least in VB). I cannot test this further so I am leaving the answer open in hopes that there is an authoritative answer to this issue. I copied an old web page and turned it into the new one I wanted and it worked. I had to move on. But why the glitchy compiler errors???